# How to get a swiping ViewPager end-to-end?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-view, swipe

I'm using a `ViewPager` with an extension of `PagerAdapter`. There are no `Fragments` involved. I'm using the `ViewPager` with regular `Views`. I noticed that when swiping through the views, the views do not remain attached/connected end-to-end. It's like an infinite margin. (There is nothing wrong with the start or end situation, only the dynamic situation during swiping.)

**How can I immediately swipe in the next page?**

To be clear: I'm seeing

[image]

and instead I would like to see:

[image]

I've noticed that using an action bar with tabs, and a FragmentPagerAdapter, and then a ViewPager together with Fragments, does have this correct behavior. Even though it also leaves gaps sometimes.

Here's my code:

**HelloTabWidget.java**:

```
package com.example.hellotabwidget;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabWidget;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloTabWidget extends Activity {

    private TabHost mTabHost;

    TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;

    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_tab_widget);

        findViews();
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    protected void findViews() {

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.realtabcontent);

        mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();

        HorizontalScrollView mScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.sv);

        TabWidget mTabWidget = (TabWidget) findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);

        mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager, mTabHost, mTabWidget, mScrollView);

        TabHost.TabSpec tab;
        tab = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1")
                .setIndicator("TABLATURE_1_IT_IS").setContent(R.id.textview1);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(tab, R.id.textview1, "tab_test1", null);

        tab = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2")
                .setIndicator("TABLATURE_2_IT_IS").setContent(R.id.textview2);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(tab, R.id.textview2, "tab_test2", null);

        tab = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test3")
                .setIndicator("TABLATURE_3_IT_IS").setContent(R.id.textview3);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(tab, R.id.textview3, "tab_test3", null);

        tab = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test4")
                .setIndicator("TABLATURE_4_IT_IS").setContent(R.id.textview4);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(tab, R.id.textview4, "tab_test4", null);

        tab = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test5")
                .setIndicator("TABLATURE_5_IT_IS").setContent(R.id.textview5);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(tab, R.id.textview5, "tab_test5", null);

        mTabsAdapter.finalizeTabs();

        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_hello_tab_widget, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * This is a helper class that implements the management of tabs and all
     * details of connecting a ViewPager with associated TabHost. It relies on a
     * trick. Normally a tab host has a simple API for supplying a View or
     * Intent that each tab will show. This is not sufficient for switching
     * between pages. So instead we make the content part of the tab host 0dp
     * high (it is not shown) and the TabsAdapter supplies its own dummy view to
     * show as the tab content. It listens to changes in tabs, and takes care of
     * switch to the correct paged in the ViewPager whenever the selected tab
     * changes.
     */
    public static class TabsAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements
            ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener, TabHost.OnTabChangeListener {
        public static final class TabInfo {
            private final Bundle args;
            private final String tag;
            private final int tabContentViewId;

            TabInfo(Bundle args, String tag, int tabContentViewId) {
                this.args = args;
                this.tag = tag;
                this.tabContentViewId = tabContentViewId;
            }

            public String getTag() {
                return tag;
            }

            public int getTabContentViewId() {
                return tabContentViewId;
            }
        }

        private Activity mContext;
        private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

        private final ViewPager mViewPager;

        private final TabHost mTabHost;

        private final TabWidget mTabWidget;

        private final HorizontalScrollView mScrollView;

        private Runnable mTabSelector;

        public TabsAdapter(Activity context, ViewPager pager, TabHost tabHost, TabWidget tabWidget, HorizontalScrollView scrollView) {
            super();
            mContext = context;
            mTabHost = tabHost;
            mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
            mViewPager = pager;
            mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
            mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
            mTabWidget = tabWidget;
            mScrollView = scrollView;
        }

        public void finalizeTabs() {
            for (int i = 0; i < getCount(); i++) {
                //mTabWidget.getChildAt(i).setFocusableInTouchMode(true);//TODO
            }

            //Keep everything in memory.
            mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(getCount());
        }

        public void addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tab, int tabContentViewId,
                String tag, Bundle args) {
            TabInfo info = new TabInfo(args, tag, tabContentViewId);
            mTabs.add(info);
            mTabHost.addTab(tab);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        /**
         * Determines whether a page View is associated with a specific key
         * object as returned by instantiateItem(ViewGroup, int). This method is
         * required for a PagerAdapter to function properly.
         * 
         * @param view
         *            Page View to check for association with object
         * @param object
         *            Object to check for association with view
         * @return
         */
        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return ((object instanceof View) && (view.getId() == ((View)object).getId()))
                    || (view == object);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mTabs.size();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
            animateToTab(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.size(); i++) {
                if (mTabs.get(i).getTag().equals(tabId)) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                    animateToTab(i);
                }
            }
        }

        public void destruct() {
            mContext = null;
        }

        /**
         * Remove a page for the given position. The adapter is responsible for
         * removing the view from its container, although it only must ensure
         * this is done by the time it returns from
         * {@link #finishUpdate(android.view.ViewGroup)}.
         * 
         * @param collection
         *            The containing View from which the page will be removed.
         * @param position
         *            The page position to be removed.
         * @param view
         *            The same object that was returned by
         *            {@link #instantiateItem(android.view.View, int)}.
         */
        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object view) {
            container.removeView((TextView) view);
        }

        /**
         * Create the page for the given position. The adapter is responsible
         * for adding the view to the container given here, although it only
         * must ensure this is done by the time it returns from
         * {@link #finishUpdate(android.view.ViewGroup)}.
         * 
         * @param collection
         *            The containing View in which the page will be shown.
         * @param position
         *            The page position to be instantiated.
         * @return Returns an Object representing the new page. This does not
         *         need to be a View, but can be some other container of the
         *         page.
         */
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            View view = mContext.findViewById(mTabs.get(position)
                    .getTabContentViewId());
            if(view==null) return null;//Might happen if ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit() is not big enough
            ViewGroup formerParent = (ViewGroup)view.getParent();
            if(formerParent!=null && formerParent.getId()==container.getId()){
                return view;
            }
            if(formerParent!=null){
                formerParent.removeView(view);
            }
            container.addView(view, 0, new ViewPager.LayoutParams());
            return view;
        }

        /**
         * Called when the a change in the shown pages has been completed. At
         * this point you must ensure that all of the pages have actually been
         * added or removed from the container as appropriate.
         * 
         * @param arg0
         *            The containing View which is displaying this adapter's
         *            page views.
         */
        @Override
        public void finishUpdate(ViewGroup container) {
            super.finishUpdate(container);
        }

        private void animateToTab(final int position) {
            final View tabView = mTabWidget.getChildAt(position);
            if (mTabSelector != null) {
                mScrollView.removeCallbacks(mTabSelector);
            }
            mTabSelector = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    final int scrollPos = tabView.getLeft()
                            - (mScrollView.getWidth() - tabView.getWidth()) / 2;
                    mScrollView.smoothScrollTo(scrollPos, 0);
                    mTabSelector = null;
                }
            };
            mScrollView.post(mTabSelector);
        }

    }
}
```

**activity_hello_tab_widget.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview50"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="some text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview60"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="some text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview70"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="some text" />

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|fill_vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/sv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:scrollbars="none" >

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" />
            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="this is a tab" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="this is another tab" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview3"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="this is a third tab" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview4"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="this is a fourth tab" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview5"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="this is a fifth tab" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0px"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Does your behavior vary by device or Android version?

Comment: Have only checked 4.2 so far. It's entirely new code. I've been staring at ViewPager/TabHost tutorials and APIs all day. It's nowadays hard to find any that don't include Fragments. Anyway, it's based of a few established tutorials (there's always a detail wrong in each of them). I also looked at geekyouup's blog post and AwesomePager code.

Comment: The hierarchyviewer does not show a wide layout. But when I remove the  ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener parts, I'm able to drag it further (so the text gets out of sight), but never to the next page. So one page seems to be the width of 3 screens. I might have to study the ViewPager again. I imagined it would lay down the pages next to each other but that doesn't seem to be happening.

Comment: Behavior is the same on 2.2 btw.

Comment: The problem seems to be in instantiateItem().

Comment: I wonder if `, new ViewPager.LayoutParams()` in instantiateItem is the culprit. That's one notable difference between your code and @Waza_Be's sample code, and in particular I wonder if that's causing each inflated view to be the full width of the pager itself. Another thing I often find useful in debugging layout issues is to set a crazy background color on each view so you can really see what's taking up the space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was me reparenting the views in `instantiateItem()`. My guess is that I was removing them from the parent at the wrong moment, hence the white infinite margin (absence of the next view). I needed to statically define the `TextViews` as children to the `ViewPager`, remove them from the `FrameLayout`, but leave in a dummy `TextView`. Then no more removing from parent is required.

Here's my fixed code:

**HelloTabWidget.java**:

```
package com.example.hellotabwidget;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabWidget;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloTabWidget extends Activity {

    private TabHost mTabHost;

    TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;

    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_tab_widget);

        findViews();
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    protected void findViews() {

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.realtabcontent);

        mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();

        HorizontalScrollView mScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.sv);

        TabWidget mTabWidget = (TabWidget) findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);

        mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager, mTabHost, mTabWidget, mScrollView);

        TabHost.TabSpec tab;
        tab = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1")
                .setIndicator("TABLATURE_1_IT_IS").setContent(R.id.dummy_textview);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(tab, R.id.textview1, "tab_test1", null);

        tab = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2")
                .setIndicator("TABLATURE_2_IT_IS").setContent(R.id.textview2);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(tab, R.id.textview2, "tab_test2", null);

        tab = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test3")
                .setIndicator("TABLATURE_3_IT_IS").setContent(R.id.textview3);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(tab, R.id.textview3, "tab_test3", null);

        tab = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test4")
                .setIndicator("TABLATURE_4_IT_IS").setContent(R.id.textview4);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(tab, R.id.textview4, "tab_test4", null);

        tab = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test5")
                .setIndicator("TABLATURE_5_IT_IS").setContent(R.id.textview5);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(tab, R.id.textview5, "tab_test5", null);

        mTabsAdapter.finalizeTabs();

        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_hello_tab_widget, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * This is a helper class that implements the management of tabs and all
     * details of connecting a ViewPager with associated TabHost. It relies on a
     * trick. Normally a tab host has a simple API for supplying a View or
     * Intent that each tab will show. This is not sufficient for switching
     * between pages. So instead we make the content part of the tab host 0dp
     * high (it is not shown) and the TabsAdapter supplies its own dummy view to
     * show as the tab content. It listens to changes in tabs, and takes care of
     * switch to the correct paged in the ViewPager whenever the selected tab
     * changes.
     */
    public static class TabsAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements
            ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener, TabHost.OnTabChangeListener {
        public static final class TabInfo {
            private final Bundle args;
            private final String tag;
            private final int tabContentViewId;

            TabInfo(Bundle args, String tag, int tabContentViewId) {
                this.args = args;
                this.tag = tag;
                this.tabContentViewId = tabContentViewId;
            }

            public String getTag() {
                return tag;
            }

            public int getTabContentViewId() {
                return tabContentViewId;
            }
        }

        private Activity mContext;
        private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

        private final ViewPager mViewPager;

        private final TabHost mTabHost;

        private final TabWidget mTabWidget;

        private final HorizontalScrollView mScrollView;

        private Runnable mTabSelector;

        public TabsAdapter(Activity context, ViewPager pager, TabHost tabHost, TabWidget tabWidget, HorizontalScrollView scrollView) {
            super();
            mContext = context;
            mTabHost = tabHost;
            mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
            mViewPager = pager;
            mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
            mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
            mTabWidget = tabWidget;
            mScrollView = scrollView;
        }

        public void finalizeTabs() {
            for (int i = 0; i < getCount(); i++) {
                //mTabWidget.getChildAt(i).setFocusableInTouchMode(true);//TODO
            }

            //Keep everything in memory.
            mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(getCount());
        }

        public void addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tab, int tabContentViewId,
                String tag, Bundle args) {
            TabInfo info = new TabInfo(args, tag, tabContentViewId);
            mTabs.add(info);
            mTabHost.addTab(tab);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        /**
         * Determines whether a page View is associated with a specific key
         * object as returned by instantiateItem(ViewGroup, int). This method is
         * required for a PagerAdapter to function properly.
         * 
         * @param view
         *            Page View to check for association with object
         * @param object
         *            Object to check for association with view
         * @return
         */
        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return ((object instanceof View) && (view.getId() == ((View)object).getId()))
                    || (view == object);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mTabs.size();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
            animateToTab(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.size(); i++) {
                if (mTabs.get(i).getTag().equals(tabId)) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                    animateToTab(i);
                }
            }
        }

        public void destruct() {
            mContext = null;
        }

        /**
         * Remove a page for the given position. The adapter is responsible for
         * removing the view from its container, although it only must ensure
         * this is done by the time it returns from
         * {@link #finishUpdate(android.view.ViewGroup)}.
         * 
         * @param collection
         *            The containing View from which the page will be removed.
         * @param position
         *            The page position to be removed.
         * @param view
         *            The same object that was returned by
         *            {@link #instantiateItem(android.view.View, int)}.
         */
        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object view) {
            container.removeView((TextView) view);
        }

        /**
         * Create the page for the given position. The adapter is responsible
         * for adding the view to the container given here, although it only
         * must ensure this is done by the time it returns from
         * {@link #finishUpdate(android.view.ViewGroup)}.
         * 
         * @param collection
         *            The containing View in which the page will be shown.
         * @param position
         *            The page position to be instantiated.
         * @return Returns an Object representing the new page. This does not
         *         need to be a View, but can be some other container of the
         *         page.
         */
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            View view = mContext.findViewById(mTabs.get(position)
                    .getTabContentViewId());
            container.addView(view, 0, new ViewPager.LayoutParams());
            return view;
        }

        /**
         * Called when the a change in the shown pages has been completed. At
         * this point you must ensure that all of the pages have actually been
         * added or removed from the container as appropriate.
         * 
         * @param arg0
         *            The containing View which is displaying this adapter's
         *            page views.
         */
        @Override
        public void finishUpdate(ViewGroup container) {
            super.finishUpdate(container);
        }

        private void animateToTab(final int position) {
            final View tabView = mTabWidget.getChildAt(position);
            if (mTabSelector != null) {
                mScrollView.removeCallbacks(mTabSelector);
            }
            mTabSelector = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    final int scrollPos = tabView.getLeft()
                            - (mScrollView.getWidth() - tabView.getWidth()) / 2;
                    mScrollView.smoothScrollTo(scrollPos, 0);
                    mTabSelector = null;
                }
            };
            mScrollView.post(mTabSelector);
        }

    }
}
```

**activity_hello_tab_widget.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview50"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="some text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview60"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="some text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview70"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="some text" />

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|fill_vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/sv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:scrollbars="none" >

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" />
            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dummy_textview"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="dummy" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0px"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="this is a tab" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="this is another tab" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview3"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="this is a third tab" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview4"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="this is a fourth tab" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview5"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="this is a fifth tab" />
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please note that this code can be further beautified and may contain some small excesses. Also, in the end, I did not go with the static views, but integrated the layout inflation idea of Waza_Be, because it is closer to `Fragments` without actually being `Fragments`, and separating a long layout seems a good idea. The functionality is identical then.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to implement a ViewPager with layouts:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
    ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    myPager.setCurrentItem(2);
}
```

With the PagerAdapter defined as:

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }
        public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            int resId = 0;
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                resId = R.layout.farleft;
                break;
            case 1:
                resId = R.layout.left;
                break;
            case 2:
                resId = R.layout.middle;
                break;
            case 3:
                resId = R.layout.right;
                break;
            case 4:
                resId = R.layout.farright;
                break;
            }
            View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
            ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
            return view;
        }
        @Override
        public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
            ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
            return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
        }
        @Override
        public Parcelable saveState() {
            return null;
        }
}
```

As I forgot my telepathic helmet, and cannot read your code, there must be something wrong out there!

Start with this simple example and try to find where is the mistake in your implementation.

Comment: Your code works on its own. I wonder if it is because of inflating the layouts. Or that my container view is just very wide (which would be a stupid mistake).

Comment: If I just create views in your method, instead of inflating the layouts, it still works.